# How to block specific network requests using the Chrome Devtools?

Tags: networking, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

So I am trying to block all requests that have the same path as domain, example:

```
https://somethingrandom/somethingrandom
```

I tried using a regex but I read somewhere regex are not supported.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome devtools (for example) support request blocking out-of-the-box. This is explained in more detail in [this article](https://tweak-extension.com/blog/how-to-block-http-request). Chrome request blocking does not support regex however it does support wildcard *. I've attached some screenshots to make this 100% clear for you.

[image: access request blocking in from "three dots" at the top right]

[image: blocking requests for URL api]

Comment: I know how network request blocking works, that was not my question. I am asking how to achieve to block a specific format of URLs that have the same domain as path: https://unknownrandomname/unknownrandomname

Comment: I don't see why request blocking wildcards would not work for you?

Comment: Huh? Wildcards block EVERYTHING. So if I did https://*/* then it'll block EVERY request and I only want those who have the same domain as path

Comment: You can do the following *unknownrandomname.com* and it will block only requests to that domain. If you want to block multiple domains you can simply add multiple block rules one per domain.

Comment: But I don't know the domain name! I only know the request has the same path as domain and I want to block all requests of that format without knowing the actual domain name